# How to open a local file with default application from browser?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, browser

I would like to create a link on a web page, which points to a local file. Click it to start a local application to open it. Is it possible? If not, can a plugin of browser or any other approach achieve it?

Comment: it is not allowed for security issue, so 
1. link to a web resource insetead, not local
2. a plugin or custom browser with bridge to call up local file
3. html5 file api, this is some kind of local, in browser sandbox file system, and not all broswer support

Answer (score 1):

URL Scheme can help you.
We are able to open a  local application  by a url like 'openmyapp://****',but you need to create a registry for your application.
ON the Windows System,the content of the registry is like this

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/Alitalk]
"URL Protocol"="openmyapp"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/Alitalk/Shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/Alitalk/Shell/Open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/Alitalk/Shell/Open/Command]
@="/"C://Program Files//Alisoft//WangWang//WangWang.EXE/" %1"
```